# Como alterar posição do Growl na tela?

Tags: java, css, jsf

Estou querendo alterar a posição do Growl porém aplico no CSS e na hora não altera nada na posição quando aparece na tela, quero centralizar por exemplo.

No template:

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Drogaria</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="estilos.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:growl id="msgGlobal" life="3000" />
...
</h:body>
```

No css:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

.ui-growl{
    left:20px;
}
```

No xhtml

```
<p:commandButton value="Gravar" actionListener="#{MBFabricante.novo}" 
                        oncomplete="PF('dlgFabNovo').hide();" 
                        update=":frmFabListagem:tblFabricantes :msgGlobal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o `absolute`, tente assim que funcionou pra mim:

```
.ui-growl {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 40%;
}
```